# Notifying iOS user that bluetooth must be turned on

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have an app that uses long-term BLE scanning in the background. I would like to detect when Bluetooth has been turned off so that I can send the user a notification saying that the apps functionality will be limited. Is this possible?

Comment: @Paulw11 thought you might be interested to know that we discovered that it actually is possible to detect in the background. I'm just now testing in the background several hours later and it's working nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conform to `CBCentralManagerDelegate` and implement `centralManagerDidUpdateState(_:)` to be notified of the change in state

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
             debugPrint("Scanner powered on")
             break
        case .poweredOff:
            debugPrint("Scanner powered off")
            break
        case .resetting:
            debugPrint("Resetting scanner")
            break
        case .unauthorized:
            debugPrint("Unauthorized")
        case .unknown:
            debugPrint("unknown")
        case .unsupported:
            debugPrint("Scanner not supported")
        }
}
```

Hope this helps